# basic haskell control statements - statement that always runs possible?

Tags: syntax, haskell, controls

If i wanted to do the following:

```
function1 stuff
| condition1 = "yay" 
| condition2 = "hey" 
| condition3 = "nay"
```

and i wanted to have a statement that always ran, unconditionally, (e.g. "because"), how could i do this? The strings are placeholders.

Thanks!

Edit:

Before i give up on this, i want to try and rephrase it in terms of the problem at hand.

I have a function which takes two inputs (lists of lists).

If given a sample input of [[]] [[[]], [[]]] (or [[]] [[["x"]], [[]]]) i want to

- test to see if there exists an even amount of [[]]'s on each side and if so delete them all
- test for an odd amount on each side then nub (delete all but one)
- several other similar things

then following this combine the two inputs (cleaned up) and return them. So far i had decided on a guard syntax, after trying case and if-then-else. But that would only allow me to test one side (for example) then after the = sign to join and return. Unless it was inordinately long... So acknowledging that i have a lot to learn yet, how would i go about doing something like this in haskell?

Comment: You're still thinking in imperative. Expressions in Haskell is not run, they are evaluated and the evaluation produces a value. If you want to factor out a common subexpression, then you can use the `where` keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions don't really apply to functional programming languages, such as Haskell.  Your first question is, I think, "how do I always do A here when I also want to do B?".  Your second question is similar: "how do I do A then B?".  These questions make sense for imperative languages (such as OO languages) where your program essentially tells the computer *how* to proceed.  In functional languages, however, you say *what* you want computed, but it's entirely up to the compiler *how* this is done (take that with a pinch of salt, but that's the general idea).

For example, your second question has

```
number = number * 5
number = number * 2
```

In an imperative language this reads "update the memory cell named 'number' with its current contents times 5; *then* update the the memory cell named 'number' with its current contents times 2".

In a functional programming language these statements are either an error (you're trying to define a scalar quantity "number" in terms of itself) or are Boolean expressions ("is number equal to number * 5?").

The best advice I can offer to help clear up your confusion is this: forget all about the idea of updating variables in a functional programming language because you can't do it.  Instead, think of always computing the value you want.  For example, here's the list length function:

```
length []     = 0                 -- The empty list has zero items.
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs     -- The non-empty list (x:xs) has one more item than xs.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As has been pointed out - im oh so slowly getting my head around the thinking required for haskell. But i guess that only comes with practice and time.

And yes that did help!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a condition that succeeds if all the others fail, then just use `otherwise`:

```
foo x
    | x == 0 = "yay"
    | x == 1 = "hey"
    | x >= 2 = "nay"
    | otherwise = "negative"
```

If you mean something else by "always ran", i.e. it would "run" even if another one also runs, then I think you are thinking wrong for this language.  For example, if we had the syntax:

```
foo x
    | x == 1 = "one"
    | always = "any"
```

Then what should be the value of `foo 1` ?

Comment: True, i still haven't managed to get my head around haskell thinking. But i am at a point in a project where i have a function that is almost right - but would need a statement to be run after the guards do their job. I guess i would have to make another function or figure out a way to include it in the "yay/hey" statement, ugly as that would be (and long...).

Comment: And re your second example, i was intending the like of 

foo x,
    x = 2 * x,
    | x == 1 = "one",

however bad that looks (commas signifying line break)...

Answer (score 2):

The only purpose of a function is to return a value. If you, however, have some commonality that each condition shares you can use `where`

```
function1 stuff
  | condition1 = "yay" ++ otherstuff
  | condition2 = "hey" ++ otherstuff
  | condition3 = "nay" ++ otherstuff
  where otherstuff = "!"
```